# Calculating Mean Square Displacement for a single particle in 1d

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I have a particle trajectory in 1D, `j=[]` and for the `time=np.arange(0, 10 + dt, dt)` where `dt` is the time step. I have calculate the MSD according to [this article](http://web.mit.edu/savin/Public/.Tutorial_v1.2/Introduction.html).

I have searched in google as well as here for 1d MSD in python but did not find any suitable one as my python knowledge is very beginner level. I have written one code and it is working without any error but I am not sure that it represent the same thing according to the given article. Here is my code,

```
j_i = np.array(j)
MSD=[]
diff_i=[]
tau_i=[]
for l in range(0,len(time)):
    tau=l*dt
    tau_i.append(tau)
    for i in range(0,(len(time)-l)):
        diff=(j_i[l+i]-j_i[i])**2

        diff_i.append(diff)

    MSD_j=np.sum(diff_i)/np.max(time)
    MSD.append(MSD_j)
```

Can anyone please check verify the code and give suggestion if it is wrong.

Comment: Because you are explicitly asking for a code review, your question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ohh sorry i did not know about that. @BramVanroy

Comment: Ignore suggestions to move questions to CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is mostly correct, here is a modified version where:

- I simplified some expressions (e.g. `range`)
- I corrected the average, directly using `np.mean` because the MSD is a squared displacement [L^2], not a ratio [L^2] / [T].

Final code:

```
j_i    = np.array(j)
MSD    = []
diff_i = []
tau_i  = []

for l in range(len(time)):
    tau = l*dt
    tau_i.append(tau)

    for i in range(len(time)-l):
        diff = (j_i[l+i]-j_i[i])**2
        diff_i.append(diff)

    MSD_j = np.mean(diff_i)
    MSD.append(MSD_j)
```

**EDIT:** I realized I forgot to mention it because I was focusing on the code, but the ensemble average denoted by <.> in the paper should, as the name implies, be performed over several particles, preferentially comparing the initial position of each particle with its new position after a time `tau`, and not as you did with a kind of time-running average

**EDIT 2:** here is a code that shows how to do a proper ensemble average to implement exactly the formula in the article

```
js     = # an array of shape (N, M), with N the number of particles and
         # M the number of time points
MSD_i  = np.zeros((N, M))
taus   = []

for l in range(len(time)):
    taus.append(l*dt)  # store the values of tau

    # compute all squared displacements at current tau
    MSD_i[:, l] = np.square(js[:, 0] - js[:, l])

# then, compute the ensemble average for each tau (over the N particles)
MSD = np.mean(MSD_i, axis=0)
```

And now you can plot `MSD` versus `taus` and Bob's your uncle

Comment: Is it not necessary to divide the mean by time?

Comment: No, at least if `j` is indeed a position (look at the unit of the MSD in [the article](http://web.mit.edu/savin/Public/.Tutorial_v1.2/Introduction.html): it is in micrometer squared); the <.> operator is just an average, which is here done over discrete values, so no time is involved

Comment: ok. got it. thanks for your correction.

Comment: I just realized I forgot an important note on the physics part, please see the edit

Comment: so for many particles, I have to calculate the MSD by the same way using the final code for each particle and then sum all the MSD and divide by the number of particle right?

Comment: I updated the answer